# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3 x}{1+x}\arcsin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x.$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions

I'm looking for evaluation of the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3 x}{1+x}\arcsin^2\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x.$$
I've tried some trivial substitutions and series expansions so far but it didn't get me anything satisfactory. I'm wondering if there's a closed form for this integral in terms of classical special functions and constants?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried putting this on calculation systems. None returned a closed form expression. If I may, where did you find this?

Comment: The question comes with a poor context. I understand that it is hard to attack the integral, but please give more information. Where did the integral show up, why is this important, why should we expect an explicit formula involving more or less elementary functions and constants? Also please type the own first trials and err's - the answerers will type more.

Comment: Why is the tag sequences-and-series in there?

Answer (score 7):

Just a beginning.

$$\arcsin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}} $$

and

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n \log^3(x)}{1+x}\,dx = \sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m\int_{0}^{1} x^{n+m}\log^3(x)\,dx = -6\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+n+1)^4} $$
so our integral equals
$$ 3\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}\sum_{m > n}\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+1)^4}=-\frac{7\pi^4}{120}\log^2\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-3\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+1)^4} $$
which *should* be related to Euler sums with weigth $6$.

Comment: any idea how to relate it to Euler sums? I know that the inner sum is $\overline{H}_{n+1}^{(4)}$.

Comment: It might be possible to compute the integral through Leshchiner's identity (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-15/issue-3/Experimental-Determination-of-Ap%C3%A9ry-like-Identities-for-zeta2n2/em/1175789759.pdf), but it doesn't seem to be an easy job. A non-alternating version of our series appears at (5-1).

Comment: Sorry Jack ! I was typing my edit (being blind requires time to do it) and I "saw" your answer after saving mine.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: sir, you never have to apologize :)

Comment: I think that I improved my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Use a series expansion of
$$\frac{\Bigg[\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\Bigg]^2}{x+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,x^n$$ and use (a few integrations by parts)
$$\int x^n\,\log^3(x)\,dx =\frac{x^{n+1} \left((n+1)^3 \log ^3(x)-3 (n+1)^2 \log ^2(x)+6 (n+1) \log
   (x)-6\right)}{(n+1)^4}$$
$$\int_0^1 x^n\,\log^3(x)\,dx =-\frac{6}{(n+1)^4}$$

If you use an expansion to $O\left(x^7\right)$, the decimal representation of the result is $-0.08048$ while numerical integration gives $-0.08069$.

**Edit**

Much better would be to use
$$\Bigg[\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\Bigg]^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{4 (n+1)^2 \binom{2 n+1}{n}}$$ and
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac {x^{n+1}}{x+1}\,\log^3(x)\,dx =-\frac{6}{(n+1)^4}+\frac{1}{16} \left(\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(3)}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\right)$$

We know the first part

$$S_1=-\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{ (n+1)^6 \binom{2 n+1}{n}}=-\frac{3}{2} \,
   _7F_6\left(1,1,1,1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2,2,2,2;\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ which, numerically is $$S_1=-1.508029564434807859364032\cdots$$

For the second part, if we let
$$a_n=-\frac{\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(3)}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{64 (n+1)^2 \binom{2 n+1}{n}}$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{11}{8 n}+\frac{85}{16 n^2}-\frac{511}{32
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

$$a_n=\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } }{2^{2 n+3}\,n^{11/2}}\Bigg[1-\frac{27}{8 n}+\frac{553}{128 n^2}+\frac{191}{1024 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \Bigg]$$

All the above show that the summation will converge very fast.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \sum_{n=0}^p a_n & S_1+\sum_{n=0}^p a_n \\
  0 & 1.42054924424587 & -0.08748032019 \\
 1 & 1.42717014055871 & -0.08085942388 \\
 2 & 1.42732902105033 & -0.08070054338 \\
 3 & 1.42733655546868 & -0.08069300897 \\
 4 & 1.42733707613558 & -0.08069248830 \\
 5 & 1.42733712182456 & -0.08069244261 \\
 6 & 1.42733712655208 & -0.08069243788 \\
 7 & 1.42733712710382 & -0.08069243733 \\
 8 & 1.42733712717440 & -0.08069243726 \\
 9 & 1.42733712718411 & -0.08069243725 \\
 10 & 1.42733712718552 & -0.08069243725
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since $a_n$ has a simple upper bound, if we want to know where to stop the summation, we need to solve
$$\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } }{2^{2 n+3}\,n^{11/2}} \leq \epsilon$$ which gives
$$n \geq \frac{11}{4 \log (2)}\,\,W\left(\frac{2 \log (2)}{11}\left(\frac{288 \pi }{\epsilon^2}\right)^{\frac 1 {11}}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

If $\epsilon=10^{-k}$, for $k \geq 6$, a good approximation is
$$n \sim 4.26567+1.68146 k-5.67925 \log (k)$$

**Update**

Using $n$ terms in the initial expansion gives as a result
$$A_n=-\frac {a_n}{b_n}+\frac {c_n}{d_n}\pi^4$$

$A_{100}$ is

$$-\frac{944625310296822422725128343436833995663832190235528173269272430121035643
   }{676428576453732757696907435157256036402189073050626346524672000000000000}$$
$$+\frac{499006958747810323870968849569}{36941729688398957008812825600000}\pi^4$$

**New elements**

The appearance of $\pi^4$ made me thinking about another approach which could be interesting for the generalization

$$I_m=\int_0^1\frac{\Bigg[\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\Bigg]^2}{x+1} \log^m(x)\,dx$$ since
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1} }{x+1}\log ^m(x) \,dx=(-1)^m \frac{m!}{2^{m+1}}  \left(\zeta \left(m+1,\frac{n+2}{2}\right)-\zeta
   \left(m+1,\frac{n+3}{2}\right)\right)$$ which gives
$$I_m=(-1)^m  \frac{m!}{2^{m+3}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\zeta \left(m+1,\frac{n+2}{2}\right)-\zeta
   \left(m+1,\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}{(n+1)^2 \binom{2 n+1}{n}}$$

$$I_m=(-1)^m \sqrt \pi \frac {m!}{2^{m+4}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{2^{2n}\,(n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\left(\zeta \left(m+1,\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-\zeta
   \left(m+1,\frac{n+3}{2}\right)\right)$$

$$I_{2p}=\sqrt \pi \frac {(2p)!}{2^{2(p+2)}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{2^{2n}\,(n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\left(\zeta \left(2p+1,\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-\zeta
   \left(2p+1,\frac{n+3}{2}\right)\right) $$
$$I_{2p+1}=-\frac {\sqrt \pi }{2^{2p+5} }\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{2^{2n}\,(n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\left(\psi ^{(2 p+1)}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(2
   p+1)}\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: How does this all yield any closed form though? You haven't explicitly mentioned this in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Permutator. I do not think that we could find a closed form or it would be extremely difficult (look at Jack's comment about   a possible approach  through Leshchiner's identity

Comment: Interesting. I have now managed to conjecture a closed expression for it that numerically holds true. Would you be able to prove it?

Comment: @Permutator. What is it ? I am more that curious. Thanks & cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

If to take a closer look at the integrand then it turns out that the main line segment that contributes to the integral is concentrated in a small zone near zero.

Extreme point of the integrand lies at $x=0.044$ and after that the integrand quickly approaches zero.

That means we can try to compute (*approximately*) the integral using the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of $\arcsin^2(x)$

$$\arcsin^2(x)=x^2+\frac{x^4}{3}+...$$

We get

$$I_{approx}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{48}}{1+x}\log^3(x)\,dx =\frac{77\pi^4-7965}{5760}$$

The approximation error is about $0.00005$